# SQL Query to find the ID with highest difference of contents

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a newbie to SQL (Server) and the following question is really making me clueless.

```
ID  Order Type    
=====================    
26  Automatic Orders    
26  Backend Orders    
41  Automatic Orders    
58  Automatic Orders    
86  Automatic Orders    
86  Automatic Orders    
86  Automatic Orders    
111 Automatic Orders    
104 Automatic Orders    
112 Backend Orders    
112 Backend Orders    
119 Backend Orders    
119 Backend Orders    
119 Backend Orders
```

Now it is asked to find "The hotel which has more number of automatic orders and less backend orders ?"

Though I was able to answer most of the questions came along with this, I'm really not getting what should I do to crack this!

Comment: I think SQL window functions will be your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is exactly what you need,
but It can guide you to the solution.

If I understood correctly,
You want the hotel in which the difference between the automatic and backend orders is the highest?

If so, 
this may help.

Assuming such table exists, and is populated with the values you provided:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This query should return the hotel list sorted according to the demand.

```
SELECT  a.HotelId , a.NumOfAutomaticOrders - a.NumOfBackendOrders
FROM    
(
    SELECT  Id as HotelId , 
    sum(case when [type] = 'Automatic Orders' then 1 else 0 end ) NumOfAutomaticOrders,
    sum(case when [type] = 'Backend Orders' then 1 else 0 end ) NumOfBackendOrders
    FROM Orders
    where 1=1
    group by Id 
) a
order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want Hotels with more `Automatic Orders` than `Backend Orders`. You can use `SUM` and `HAVING` function for this.

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM temp
GROUP BY ID
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Order Type] = 'Automatic Orders' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Order Type] = 'Backend Orders' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

## EDIT

As per your comment on Asketh's answer, this is probaby what you need:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 *
FROM(
    SELECT
        ID,
        [Automatic Orders] = SUM(CASE WHEN [Order Type] = 'Automatic Orders' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        [Backend Orders] = SUM(CASE WHEN [Order Type] = 'Backend Orders' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM temp
    GROUP BY ID
)t
ORDER BY ([Automatic Orders] - [Backend Orders]) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    a.cnt,  
    b.cnt 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, COUNT(ordertype) cnt 
    FROM tab
    WHERE ordertype = 'Automatic Order' 
    GROUP BY id
) a
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id, COUNT(ordertype) cnt 
    FROM tab
    WHERE ordertype = 'Backend Order' 
    GROUP BY id
) b
ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE a.cnt> b.cnt
```

**EDIT**: 
If you want the hotel with highest difference, do the below:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    ID, 
    a.cnt,  
    b.cnt 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, COUNT(ordertype) cnt 
    FROM tab
    WHERE ordertype = 'Automatic Order' 
    GROUP BY id
) a
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id, COUNT(ordertype) cnt 
    FROM tab
    WHERE ordertype = 'Backend Order' 
    GROUP BY id
) b
ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE a.cnt> b.cnt
```

ORDER BY (a.cnt-b.cnt)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as following: first find hotels with Max count of Automatic Orders and among them find hotel with minimum Backend Orders. If this is true then this query works

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT, Type NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES(26, 'Automatic Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(26, 'Backend Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(41, 'Automatic Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(58, 'Automatic Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(86, 'Automatic Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(86, 'Automatic Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(86, 'Automatic Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(111, 'Automatic Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(104, 'Automatic Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(104, 'Automatic Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(104, 'Automatic Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(112, 'Backend Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(112, 'Backend Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(119, 'Backend Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(119, 'Backend Orders')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES(119, 'Backend Orders');



WITH cte AS
(
SELECT ao.ID, ao.Count AS AutomaticOrdersCount, ISNULL(bo.Count, 0) AS BackendOrdersCount FROM 
(
SELECT ID, Type, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM @t
WHERE Type = 'Automatic Orders'
GROUP BY ID, Type
)ao
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT ID, Type, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM @t
WHERE Type = 'Backend Orders'
GROUP BY ID, Type
)bo ON bo.ID = ao.ID
ORDER BY ao.Count DESC, ISNULL(bo.Count, 0) ASC
)
SELECT * FROM cte 
WHERE AutomaticOrdersCount = (SELECT MAX(AutomaticOrdersCount) FROM cte) AND 
        cte.BackendOrdersCount = (SELECT TOP 1 BackendOrdersCount FROM cte)
ORDER BY cte.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank each of you for trying to help me out. I got many ideas through the queries that you suggested. as @Y.S said, I also think finding the hotel in which the difference between the automatic and backend orders is the highest will untie the knot. I wrote a simple code like this, which will return the hotel which has the highest difference.

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, SUM(IIF(Order_Type='Automatic orders',1,-1)) AS Score
FROM P1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY score DESC
```

This returns me the answer, but I doubt is this the correct query I should write to find this. In my answer, I will get 'score (the calculation) and the corresponding hotel id.

```
Score  id
-----  ----
xx     xxx
```

*How can I avoid showing the 'score' in end result by the way?!?*

I just want to show the only the Hotel ID in the end result. Since the calculations/ conditions are in `SELECT`, I can leave `SUM(IIF(Order_Type='Automatic orders',1,-1))` also.